# Webforms Login OnAuthenticate event not firing in a child page

Tags: vb.net, webforms

I started with a Web forms login page which as been in production for several years, It has no master page and is using the Aspnet [`Webcontrols.Login`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login(v=vs.110).aspx) control.

I copied the code to new master/content pages but the `Login1_Authenticate` method is never fired on the new page.
The `Login_PreRender` event fires as it should.

I have tried deleting and adding again the `OnAuthenticate` method via Visual studio 2017.
I have tried adding `Handles Login1.Authenticate` to the `Authenticate` method but no change.
I have cleaned the build and rebuilt.
I have tried `OnAuthenticate="SomeJibberish`" and then I get an "...is not a member..." exception. So the method does get wired up.
I am using my own `<LayoutTemplate>`, copied from production code.
I am considering it imposssible to use the `Login` control in a content page.

---

Login.Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Login.master.vb" 
Inherits="MyProject.Web.LoginMaster" %>
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </form>
</body>
```

Login.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Login.Master" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.vb" 
Inherits="MyProject.Web.Login" %>
...
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server"
        OnPreRender="Login1_PreRender"
        OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"/>
        <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" ComandName="Login" Text="Login" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

Login.vb:

```
Partial Public Class Login Inherits System.Web.UIPage
...
    Protected Sub Login1_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ...is fired
    End Sub

    Protected Sub Login1_Authenticate(sender As Object, e As AuthenticateEventArgs) 
    ...is not fired
    End Sub
```

Login.aspx.designer.vb:

```
Partial Public Class Login
    Protected WithEvents Login1 As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login
```

Comment: I am going to take a guess here..can you try renaming the page to something other than Login and other thing noticed is shouldn't it be inheriting from System.Web.UI.MasterPage

Comment: @gbs I have tried renaming (and changing appropriately in `web.config`). The inheritance is correct, the content page should inherint from `Page` and not `MasterPage`. I also added some more code to the `Login.aspx` above.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. I did a quick test. Dropped Login control on a child page, converted it to a Template and it did hit the Authenticate. I used 4.5.2 Asp.net WebApplication.

Comment: You want `AutoEventWireup="false"`?

Comment: Fwiw, I was messing around with that event and had a hell of a time. What I discovered, for me, was that that event should only be used when manually calling a *custom* auth provider - not when the provider being used works automatically, but when all things are being done manually. It did fire though...

Comment: @wazz `AutoEventWireup` is if I want the event methods to be automagically wire up by their names. Conventient as but can break by "safe" refactoring like renaming a control. I prefer wiring up explicitly, with `CommandName` in my case above.

Comment: I don't know if it's just a typo but ComandName should be CommandName instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is just a small typo. The command name attribute should be CommandName instead of ComandName.

```
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Login" />
```